# extract first item from series of lists and use as index

Tags: pandas, string, series

So I start with this series containing lists, and the first item in the list is to be extracted and used as the index, and the rest of the list are strings to be joined.

```
coms = pd.Series({
    0: ['1593610', 'comment1', 'comment2'],
    1: ['1593613', 'comment4', 'comment5', 'comment6', 'comment7', 'comment9', 'comment10'],
    2: ['15936111'],
    3: ['15936112'],
    4: ['15936114'],
    5: ['15936115'],
    6: ['15936116'],
    7: ['15936117'],
    8: ['15936118', 'comment19', 'comment21', 'comment22'],
    9: ['15936123']})
```

I managed to solve it with

```
coms.index = coms.str.get(0)
coms = coms.str.slice(start=1).str.join(', ')
```

Output

```
ID
1593610                                    comment1, comment2
1593613     comment4, comment5, comment6, comment7, commen...
15936111
15936112
15936114
15936115
15936116
15936117
15936118                      comment19, comment21, comment22
15936123
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

But before that I tried something that I don't get why it did not work.

```
# works fine, returns the expected series with default index
coms = pd.Series(coms.str.slice(start=1).str.join(', '))

# works fine, returns empty series with desired index
coms = pd.Series('', index=coms.str.get(0))

# does not work!! returns a series with the desired index but all `np.nan` values
coms = pd.Series(coms.str.slice(start=1).str.join(', '), index=coms.str.get(0))

# print(coms)
ID
1593610     NaN
1593613     NaN
15936111    NaN
15936112    NaN
15936114    NaN
15936115    NaN
15936116    NaN
15936117    NaN
15936118    NaN
15936123    NaN
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `values`, without adding the `values` `coms.str.slice(start=1).str.join(', ')` still series with index from 0 to n, dose not match with new index assigned

```
pd.Series(coms.str.slice(start=1).str.join(', ').values, index=coms.str.get(0))
```